# Icons for favorite in non-beta site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Right now, when I look at a question that I have NOT selected as a favorite question, I see a yellow star under the vote counts for that question. Selecting a question as a favorite makes the yellow star turn into a white outlined star. Is this backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martha, this has been fixed. you may need to do a control+f5 for hard refresh. thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jin! I can see it now.